# Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'long'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have this error but I don't have any idea where is the problem:

**This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Mon Sep 02 12:57:36 CEST 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'long'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'long'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""**

***AgentController***

```
@RequestMapping(value="/saveOperation", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveOperation(Model model, String typeOperation,long codeCompte,double montant, long codeCompte2){
        try {
            if(typeOperation.equals("VERS")){
                agentServices.verser(codeCompte, montant);
            }
            else if(typeOperation.equals("RETR")){
                agentServices.retirer(codeCompte, montant);
            } 
            else if (typeOperation.equals("VIR")){
                agentServices.virement(codeCompte,codeCompte2,montant);
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            model.addAttribute("error",e);  
        }
        return "redirect:/consulterCompte?codeCompte="+codeCompte;
    }
```

***agent.html***

```
<form th:action="@{/saveOperation}" method="post">
<div>
<label>Compte: </label>
<input  type="hidden" name="codeCompte" th:value="${codeCompte}"/>
<label th:text="${codeCompte}"></label>
</div>
<div>
<input type="radio" name="typeOperation" value="VERS" checked="checked"  onchange="document.getElementById('forVirement').style.display='none'"/>
<label>Versement</label>
<input type="radio" name="typeOperation" value="RETR" onchange="document.getElementById('forVirement').style.display='none'"/>
<label>Retrait</label>
<input type="radio" name="typeOperation" value="VIR" onchange="document.getElementById('forVirement').style.display='block'"/>
<label>Virement</label>
</div>
<div id="forVirement" style="display:none">
<label>Transféré à:</label>
<input type="text" name="codeCompte2" />
</div>
<div>
<label>Montant:</label>
<input type="text" name="montant"/>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">OK</button>
</form>
```

Comment: What did you put in the input fields `codeCompte` and `codeCompte2`?

Comment: Can you use a Long instead of a long and handle a 'null' value in your controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add default value for `codeCompte2`

in ***agent.html***

```
<input type="text" name="codeCompte2" value="0" /> // add default value
```

Answer (score 1):

when you use input (`codeCompte` or `codeCompte2`) you don't have `value`,so post field is `"",""` default type is `String`

`springmvc` can't convert value of type `java.lang.String` to required type `long`

so :

1. you should be have `default` value 0
2. you can change `AgentController.saveOperation` method field (codeCompte and codeCompte2) type to `String` ,then `catch` in the method

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I should keep codeCompte and codeCompte2 as long

Comment: so you should be have default value 0

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you it can't convert an empty input String "" to a long value.

> Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'long'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

There are two long parameters in the method call, `codeCompte` and `codeCompte2`. This means these values have to be valid long values, but according to the error message, one of them was an empty String (i.e. no value) instead.

It looks like `codeCompte` is generated by your application, so if this is where the empty value is, there's probably some error in your code.

But more likely the problem is `<input type="text" name="codeCompte2" />`. You should somehow check in your application if the value entered in this input field is a valid number. Check out the [input type "number"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number), which would probably be better suited for this input field.